# find the lowest age and print out the corresponding name in array from a file?

Tags: java

I need help with the program that reads in names and ages from a file called Stuff.txt. I was able to Print both arrays, but I also need to find the lowest age and print out the corresponding name.My code is not working and I have no idea why? No loop or switch is necessary. My "stuff. txt" contains the following input so far:

```
  Sam 21 Ram 22 Hero 23
```

Here is what I have worked on so far:

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;
 public class nameAge
 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
  ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<Integer> ages = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("stuff.txt")); 
  int i = 0; 
  while (inFile.hasNextLine()) { 
  String line = inFile.nextLine();
  Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line); 
  while(lineScanner.hasNext()){
  names.add(lineScanner.next());
  ages.add(lineScanner.nextInt());
  }
   System.out.println(names);
   System.out.println(ages);
  }


   int idx = -1;  
   int d= 100000;  
   for( i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
     if(ages < d) 
   { 
     d = ages[i]; 
     idx = i; 
   } 
   System.out.println("Lowest age "+ ages[idx] + "Corresponding Name" + name[idx] ); 

  }
  }
```

Comment: Side-note: Please have a look at how to correctly indent code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

slight modification of the code posted by ExcelledProducts

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class NameAge {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
  ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<Integer> ages = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("stuff.txt")); 
  int i = 0; 
  while (inFile.hasNextLine()) { 
  String line = inFile.nextLine();
  Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line); 
  while(lineScanner.hasNext()){
  names.add(lineScanner.next());
  ages.add(lineScanner.nextInt());
  }
   System.out.println(names);
   System.out.println(ages);
  }

  int old_age = 0;
  int old_age_i = 0;
  int count = 0;
  for(int age : ages){
       if (old_age == 0)
            old_age = age;
       else
            if (old_age > age){
                 old_age = age;
                 old_age_i = count;
       count ++;}
            else continue;
  }
  String name = names.get(old_age_i);
  System.out.println(name);
  String theAge = ages.get(old_age_i);
  System.out.println(theAge);
  }
}
```

Comment: not necessarily better, but ran it earlier and got an issue retrieving the right age. Haven't tried her/his code after the edits.

Comment: I didn't even look tbh

Answer (score 1):

Loop through your age list and that index is the index in your name because there is a 1:1 ratio between ages and names.

Full code as requested.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> ages = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        //YOUR LOADING CODE GOES HERE

        int index = getIndexOfMin(ages);
        System.out.println(names.get(index) + " is " + ages.get(index));

    }

    public static int getIndexOfMin(ArrayList<Integer> data) {
        float min = Float.MAX_VALUE;
        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            Integer f = data.get(i);
            if (Float.compare(f.floatValue(), min) < 0) {
                min = f.floatValue();
                index = i;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }
```

Comment: I am beginner at Java. Do you mind making it more clear to me? I donot know where should I put the code that you gave me in my code

Comment: this code should replace your code from `int idx = -1;` to `System.out.println(...` I will update my answer with full code

Comment: Thank you so much. Please do update the your answer with full code.

Comment: Can you also help me to print the age, not just the name?